# What is the value of $p(+)$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I know the formula is $p = \left<\psi\right|M_{m}^{\dagger} M_{m}\left|\psi\right>$, where $\left|\psi\right>= \alpha\left|0\right>+\beta\left|1\right>$ and $M_m=\left|+\right> \left<+\right| (m=\left|+\right>)$. After all the calculations I finally got $$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\alpha^*+\beta^*}{2} & \frac{\alpha^*+\beta^*}{2}
\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \\ \beta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and its not even nearly approaching to the answer which is $1$. Kindly tell me what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Why would it be 1? It is the probability to measure $|+ \rangle$ in state $| \psi \rangle$, which is 1 only if $| \psi \rangle=|+ \rangle$

Comment: Could you provide the full question? It seems that some of the essential details are missing. For example, what does $m$ refer to? And what is $| \psi >$?

Comment: what are $M$, $M_m$, and $|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: I have made the required edits. And my prof told that the answer would be 1.

Comment: I would assume that you are trying to measure in the Hadamard basis and calculating the probability of finding the qubit in $|+\rangle$ state. That probability would be 1 if and only if the current state of the particle is equal to the $|+\rangle$ state, upto a phase.

Comment: You could treat this question more generally as follows: calculate the quantity for arbitrary $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then find the conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the answer is indeed 1.